# Silex DoctrineServiceProvider not connecting

Tags: doctrine-orm, silex, dbal

I'am building application on Silex, and I'am having some problems on very basic stuff. I used example from official documentation for using doctrine service provider, but no matter what i do `$app[ 'db' ]->isConnected()` returns false. Here is the code

```
    $app = new Application();
    $app->register(new DoctrineServiceProvider(), array(
        'dbs.options' => array (
            'mysql' => array(
                'driver'    => 'pdo_mysql',
                'host'      => 'localhost',
                'dbname'    => 'sevenbet',
                'user'      => 'root',
                'password'  => '',
                'charset'   => 'utf8',
            )
        ),
    ));
```

Comment: can you try to use 127.0.0.1 instead of *localhost*? Did you check for any error on the log?

Comment: IIRC it lazy-connects, did you try to run a query and check isConnected after that?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use multi dimension array, if you have one db config to provide, just use :

```
$app['db.options'] = array (
    'driver'    => 'pdo_mysql',
    'host'      => 'localhost',
    'dbname'    => 'mydb',
    'user'      => 'root',
    'password'  => 'root',
    'charset'   => 'utf8'
);
```